# Software to automatically change the wallpaper depending on the screen orientation

Tags: windows

Okay so as the title specifies, I'm looking for a software that will automatically change what the wallpaper is depending on the screen orientation. The software needs to run on windows 8.1, the software needs to;

- Change the wallpaper when screen orientation changes.
- Needs to detect that the screen orientation changes and alter the wallpaper accordingly.

Those are the main features that I'm looking for, I would appreciate it if the software is free and has no ads, however i don't mind there being ads.

Thanks in advance.